# Trade-offs between phage and yeast displays?

Tags: molecular-biology, immunology

If you wanted to test a peptide you designed, you can do a [phage display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phage_display) or a [yeast display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeast_display) experiment to assess binding affinity.

What are the trade-offs between these two methods?

I've heard anecdotally that yeast display is more sensitive and closer to human cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Creative Biolabs](https://www.creative-biolabs.com/surface-technology-faq.html), the primary differences are:

> 1. In the screening/panning step, yeast display is suitable for Fluorescence Activated Cell Sorting (FACS), allowing to sort out antibodies with desired binding properties
>    precisely. However, the affinity of antibodies to antigens in phage
>    display can only be roughly stratified (sorted into categories of goodness) by adjusting the washing buffer
>    compositions.
> 2. Owing to its eukaryotic expression system, yeast displayed antibodies can be correctly folded and modified, such as [...] to be closer to their native structure in mammals
>    compared to the antibodies expressed by E.coli in phage display.
> 3. The diversity of yeast displayed antibodies may be lower than phage (107-109 for yeast, up to 1011 for phage), due to the low
>    transformation efficiency of yeast.
> 4. Due to the many more copies of antibody on yeast surface (104-105) than phage, it is possible to select out low affinity antibodies
>    according to antibody avidity with yeast display system.

Anecdotally, phage display is also cheaper.